# How to refer to the Webdriver object in selenium without making it static to take screenshot through Testng listeners on Test Failure

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, testng, listener

Hi Im stuck in a situation where I have declared my driver object in the test class and I have some wrappers developed in another class , all the respective variables are **not static** including the driver object , so now I want to take a screenshot on failure using testng listerners **(I have created a custom listener class implementing to ITestListener)** and when I refer to the driver object it throws a null exception probably due to driver not been static , how can I still achieve to take a screenshot without making the driver static , any testng related work around will also be helpful

this is the code line in my custom listenerclass

```
onTestFailure(){
    bufferImage = driver.getScreenshot(); //throws null , getScreesnshot comes from my wrapper class
}
```

I want to take the screenshot on test failure using testng listeners , without making the driver object static

Comment: If you don't want to make the WebDriver object static ,  you can inherit the class with webdriver or you can use a approach such as dependency injection

Comment: @AbhayChaudhary can you explain more on the dependency injection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your driver object to test context and then take if from test context in `onFailure` method. Here is short example where everython is in single class but it would be working just fine in multi-class case as well:

```java
@Listeners({TestL.class})
public class TestL implements ITestListener {

    
    
    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp(ITestContext context){
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        // Put object to context
        context.setAttribute("myDriver", driver);
    }

    @Test
    public void toFail(){
        Assert.fail();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        System.out.println("Test failed..");
        // Take object from context and do some actions
        File screenShot = ((TakesScreenshot)result
                .getTestContext()
                .getAttribute("myDriver")).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    }
}
```

Do not forget to `quit` your session appropriately.

Comment: thanks for the solution.

Another question if you have the context of working with Playwright ,  so the same approach how can I implement for Playwright with Java , cuz if we are to create multiple pages from a context we might need to set all the page objects as below ryt?

   context.setAttribute("page1", page1);
   context.setAttribute("page2", page2);

Comment: I think you need to raise another question regarding your new issue.